# how to get the timestamp of kernel for linux real time operating system ??

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, embedded, real-time

Client is a tool for sending a data. Server is a embedded PC target with Linux RT (real time) in it.  Initially target will be executing some other task. When the new data arrives from the client then the server will be interrupted and server schedules the newly arrived task!! I want to get the timestamp when it is interrupted and when kernel starts scheduling.

I should modify the source code of kernel to get the timestamp of the kernel and someone please tell me where and how should i do this ??

how to get the timestamp of kernel ??
where should i modify the code in kernel source ??

Comment: Why don't you make that a user-land server application on the embedded Linux? No need to hack the kernel!! Then read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html)

Comment: my server is real time linux operating system. I am analyzing the time when the interrupt occurs and time when the kernel starts executing. To get the kernel time - how is it possible from the user space ?? operating system operations like scheduling, IPC, interrupts and so on will take place in kernel mode not in user space.